# How Do I Calculate Average Share Price?

Tags: stocks, trading

If have 3,000,000 shares at an average price of 10.8¢ per share and want to purchase another 50,000 shares at 60¢ per share in same company, what will my average price per share change to?

Comment: Is this your homework?

Answer (score 2):

The answer would be 11.6c per share.  Simple math:

3,000,000 times $.108 per share  = $324,000

50,000 times $.60 per share = $30,000

$324,000 + $30,000 = $354,000 divided by 3,050,000 shares = $.11606 per share.

Although to be honest I'm not sure why you'd be making the additional 50,000 share purchase at almost 6 times the cost of the first 3 million shares.  Hmmm....

Comment: Obviously because they believe the stock will continue to increase over time.

Comment: Curious why this was downvoted, it answers the question just fine, no?

Comment: Hard to know.  Votes are a matter of peoples' opinions.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not always the case, usually people average down the price,so they will make more profit when the stock price goes up (assuming they take profit at the higher price). Buying the dips is one of the long term investor strategies.  As you can see from the other answer your average will go up from 10.8 to 11.6 if you acquire those additional 50K shares. Is there a reason for you to average up at this point?